# Is $(C([-1,1]),\|\cdot\|_2)$ Complete?

Tags: metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, complete-spaces

Here,

$$\left\|f\right\|_2=\left(\int_{-1}^1\left|f(t)\right|^2\,dt\right)^{1/2},$$

where the integral is a Riemann integral.

I am confused because $\{f_n\}$, where $f_n(t)=|t|^n$, is Cauchy with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$ but converges pointwise to a discontinuous function. However, it converges to $f\equiv0$ with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$.

Do we care about the fact that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to a discontinuous function?

Comment: Your title expresses a concern about "completeness", a notion based on metric topolgy, but phrased as "with Respect to Riemann integration", and this makes the Question posed "Do we even care about pointwise convergence in this case" confusing.  Perhaps you could edit the body of the Question  (and its title) so that Readers will have a clearer problem statement to work with.

Comment: @hardmath, I made some changes that hopefully clarified my concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the example you gave does not provide evidence that the space is not complete, because it is a Cauchy sequence that does have a limit in the space.  By creating an example with similar behavior, but having a jump in the middle instead of only an endpoint, you can demonstrate that the space has a Cauchy sequence with no limit in the space.

E.g., $f_n(t) =\sqrt[n]{\max(0,t)}$.  It is relevant in proving this sequence has no limit in the space to consider its pointwise convergence, because if it were convergent it would also have a subsequence converging pointwise a.e. to the limit function, whereas any function equal almost everywhere to the pointwise limit of $f_n$ is discontinuous at $0$.  But you don't need to think in those terms, if you know by other means that limits with respect to this norm are unique *up to equivalence a.e.*.

Comment: This explanation removed my confusion. Thank you!